# CodeIgniter: return FALSE if Active Record can't find any data

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Using CodeIgniter, I find the following code in all the models that gathers data from a database:

```
// .. taken from function get_user_data($user_id)
// Select data
$user_data = $this->db->from('users')->where('id', $user_id)->get()->row();

// Check if we got any matches
if(isset($user_data->id)) {

  // Indeed we did, return the data found
  return $user_data

} else {

   // Nope, no data found
   return FALSE;

}
```

The interesting part is where I check if the query actually returned any data. I'm doing that for EVERY query, which adds up to quite a bit **repetitive code**.

Is there any way to, perhaps override the CodeIgniter functions, making them **return `FALSE` if no data was found**? 
I'm probably missing something, as I can't see why CodeIgniter isn't handling this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with wesley murch option but i think creating a entire class for an individual function isn't good practice. My opinion is to use helpers. You can try this:

In Helper File:

```
function get_db_data($result)
{
    return ( $result->num_rows() > 0 ) ? $result->result_array() : false;
}
```

You can call this function in any of your model with

```
$this->load->helper('helper_file_name');
$dbData = get_db_data(result_object);
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much in the way of built in shortcuts. Even the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) suggests checking your results:

> If you run queries that might not produce a result, you are encouraged to test the result first:
>
> ```
> $query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
> if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
> {
>    // found results
> }
> ```

You could always use a class extension:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    protected function _get_row($result)
    {
        return $result->num_rows() ? $result->row() : FALSE;
    }

}
```

Usage in a model:

```
function get_user_data($user_id)
{
    $user_data = $this->db->from('users')->where('id', $user_id)->get();
    return $this->_get_row($user_data);
}
```

You'd just have to `extends MY_Model` for the models you want to have access to the function.

Another option would be to return the result of `$this->db->get()` instead, and do the check in your controller (which you would probably have to do anyways).